# How to fix a string input that give the wrong output?

Tags: java

I have compiled and ran the code. It works but it's not giving me the  correct output.

I should get when the user types Kelly, it should say "Names accepted". However, it says " names not accepted. Can somebody help me?

```
package compare;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Democompare{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Try a match!");
        korean();
    }

    public static void korean()
    {
        String [] names1 = {"Kelly"};
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your answer:");
        String  ans1 = sc.nextLine();
        if(ans1 == names1[0])
        {
            System.out.println("Names accepted!");
        }

        else if(ans1 != names1[0]){
            System.out.println("Names not accepted!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `ans1 == names1[0]` for `ans1.equals(names1[0])`. When you compare using `==` you compare the object by reference instead of by value.

Comment: should be if (ans1.equals(names1[0]))

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ans1.equals(names1[0])` rather than `==`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked every but no other sources helped me.